# disabling html div when theres no value needed

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hello I want to disable an `<img>` tag inside a certain `<div>` when there's no image inputted by the user.

```
if(is_array($init) || is_object($init)){
    foreach ($init as $data) {
        echo '
            <div id="profile-page-wall-post" class="card">
                <div class="card-profile-title">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s1">
                            <img src="'.base_url('assets/images/'.$data->accounts_picture.'').'" 
                              alt="" class="circle responsive-img valign profile-post-uer-image">                       
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s10">
                            <p class="grey-text text-darken-4 margin">'.$data->accounts_fname."\t".$data->accounts_lname.'</p>
                            <span class="grey-text text-darken-1 ultra-small">Shared publicly  '.$data->post_date.'</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row center-align">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <img class="Boxing image_attached" src="'.base_url('assets/files/'.$data->post_picture.'').'">
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <p>'.$data->post_content.'</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12">
                            <a href="'.base_url('assets/files/'.$data->post_file.'').'" download>'.$data->post_filename.'</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action row">
                    <div class="input-field col s8 margin">
                        <input id="profile-comments" type="text" 
                          class="validate margin">
                        <label for="profile-comments" class="">
                            Comments
                        </label>
                    </div>                 
                </div> 
                <div id="CommentSection" class="z-depth-1 col s12">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                            <div class="row valign-wrapper">
                                <div class="col s2">
                                    <img src="assets/images/def.jpg" 
                                      alt="" class="circle responsive-img"> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s10">
                                    <p>Comment content</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

I wanted to disable the `<div>` with the `<img>` inside, if `$data->post_picture` is null. How can I do this?

Comment: Formatted the code and added some grammar and spelling changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this is tagged with jQuery and Javascript, since all you seem to be using is PHP, so why don't you just:

```
// ... (end your echo)
'; 
if(!empty($data->post_picture)){
  echo '
  <div class="row center-align">
    <div class="col s12">
      <img class="Boxing image_attached" src="'.base_url('assets/files/'.$data->post_picture.'').'">
    </div>  
  </div>
  '; 
} 
echo ' // (continue your echo)
// ...
```

Please also not that you may have a syntax error at `"'.base_url('assets/files/'.$data->post_picture.'').'"` (you're closing and opening '' but this actually closes your echo '. You're using single quotes (')  around what you're echoing, then double quotes around the `img src=""`, and then single quotes around the `base_url` again, which I think (I'm not sure, since the code is so messy and I get confused by all the quotes) results in a syntax error over here: `'').'`.

Comment: i am sorry that i tagged it how do i retagg? thank you i got it